# How does one poll for transfer events using Nethereum?

Tags: nethereum

I have a contract deployed on Goerli test network, given the code below, I never see any event changes when I transfer tokens.

```csharp
 public static async Task PollForEvents(JObject pixelBlock)
        {
            try
            {
                var web3 = new Web3(Env.INFURA_GOERLI);
                string abi = pixelBlock["abi"].ToString();
                var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(abi, Env.PIXEL_BLOCK_GOERLI);
               
                Event transferEvent = contract.GetEvent("Transfer");
                Nethereum.Hex.HexTypes.HexBigInteger transferEventFilter = await transferEvent.CreateFilterAsync();

                Event<TransferEventDTO> transferEventHandler = web3.Eth.GetEvent<TransferEventDTO>(Env.PIXEL_BLOCK_GOERLI);
                NewFilterInput filterAllTransferEventsForContract = transferEventHandler.CreateFilterInput();
           
                while (true)
                {
                    List<EventLog<TransferEventDTO>> getAllChanges0 = await transferEvent.GetAllChangesAsync<TransferEventDTO>(transferEventFilter);
                    List<EventLog<TransferEventDTO>> getAllChanges1 = await transferEventHandler.GetAllChangesAsync(filterAllTransferEventsForContract);
                    List<EventLog<TransferEventDTO>> getAllChanges2 = await transferEvent.GetFilterChangesAsync<TransferEventDTO>(transferEventFilter);

                    if (getAllChanges0.Count > 0 || getAllChanges1.Count > 0 || getAllChanges2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(getAllChanges0.Count);
                        Console.WriteLine(getAllChanges1.Count);
                        Console.WriteLine(getAllChanges2.Count);
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

[image]